# No create() method in Drive.Files

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Trying to make an application that uploads a generated JSON file to Google Drive. It checks if the required folder is present in the Drive. If not, it creates one. The method that creates folders is as follows:

```
public static String createFolder(String folderName) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    // authorization
    Credential credential = authorize();

    // set up the global Drive instance
    drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("xyz")
            .build();

    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(folderName);
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

    File file = drive.files()
            .create(fileMetadata) // Not Recognised (Shows - Cannot find symbol)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();

    return file.getId();
}
```

The folder creation part was taken from this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#creating_a_folder). But it seems there is no `create()` method. Tried to find if there is a way to create just files and found [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create#create_a_new_file_from_the_drive_ui). It has a similar code for creating files but the heading seems to indicate that it doesn't create a file, it just creates a link.

What is the issue here? Can't I create folders in Google Drive using Java? If I can, then are there any other classes or methods that I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `v2` JARs for Google Drive but your code appears to be for `v3`.  If you want to use `v3`, then include the appropriate JARs.  If you are using a Maven project, just drop this in your POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev20-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3#sample) to the official documentation where you can download the JAR and get more information for Drive `v3`.

Comment: Yup. That was the issue. Updated the POM. Thanks!